# Draggable DIV using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make Draggable div
i know this can be done using Jquery plug in but I don't want to use because I just need only draggable function.
so how can I make draggable function 
I have did this

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
                $("#eve").mousemove(function(e){
                    var p=$(this);
                    var offset = p.offset();
                    var ol=offset.left;
                    var ot=offset.top;
                    var l=e.pageX-ol;
                    var t=e.pageY-ot;
                    var eX=e.pageX;
                    var eY=e.pageY;
                    var htm="left:"+ol+" top:"+ot+"<br/>";
                    htm+="eX:"+eX+" eY:"+eY+"<br/>";
                    htm+="curX:"+l+" curY:"+t+"<br/>";
                    htm+="l:"+(ol-l)+" t:"+(ot-t);
                    p.html(htm);
                   p.css({left:((eX-3))+"px",top:((eY-3))+"px"});
                });
```

Comment: What does your code do? How does the HTML look like?

Comment: there is one DIV in html

Comment: You can just use only the draggable component of jQuery UI? There is no need to download the entirety of jQuery UI to use drag, it seems you can select which components you want on the download page.

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery UI?  I'd recommend using it so that you don't spend a lot of time making something that already exists.

Comment: @WizardofOgz I agree with you absolutely, however it doesn't take so much time to implement it.

Comment: @Aeolun i was not knowing that single component can download

Comment: how can i download that function ?

Comment: On [`jqueryui.com`](http://jqueryui.com) in the download section you can create a download package by yourself by selective needed components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define multiple function to handle the `mousedown` event to start drag, `mouseup` to stop draging, and appropriate `mousemove` to handle the movements while dragging, check this gist i found https://gist.github.com/1330150

Comment: how do i apply this function to my element ?

Comment: check the usage part - first 5 lines of the gist

Answer (score 5):

Here is my fast improvisation. Maybe this is exactly you are looking for.

```
$("div").on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        var data = el.data("down");
        if (data) {
            el.css({
                left: e.pageX - data.left,
                top: e.pageY - data.top
            });
        }
    },
    mousedown: function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        var pos = el.offset();
        el.data("down", {
            left: e.pageX - pos.left,
            top: e.pageY - pos.top
        });
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        $(this).data("down", false);
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UBKBb/